# How can I generalize "field name" variable?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import math

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("NVF_*")

try:
    for fc in fcs:
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            if row.Field_ID == 1:
                rows.deleteRow(row)
        del rows, row
# This code adds up several fields like Ratio_NDVI, Ratio_Acres etc.
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "Ratio_NDVI", "float")
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "Ratio_Area", "float")
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, "Final", "integer")-
 # This code calculates area in square meter using existing datum coordinates of the vector file
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "NewArea", "DOUBLE")
        geometryField = arcpy.Describe(fc).shapeFieldName
        cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
            AreaValue = row.getValue(geometryField).area
            row.setValue("NewArea", AreaValue)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        del row, cursor
  # This code converts square meter into acres
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            row.NewArea = (row.NewArea*0.00024711)
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
   # This code calculates ratio of NDVI of child_fields to the average NDVI of parent field
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            if row.NDVI090606 == 0: 
                row.Ratio_NDVI = (row.M090606/row.M090606) 
            else:
                row.Ratio_NDVI = (row.M090606/row.NDVI090606) 
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
   # This code calculates the ratio of acres of child fields to their corresponding parent field
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            row.Ratio_Area = (row.NewArea/row.Acres)
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
        print ("Completed calculating ratio of acres")
   # This code finds that field that has either Ratio_NDVI higher than 1.5 to its parent #field or less than 0.5 to its parent field and Ratio_Acres higher than 0.05. Then #comments this field as "Change"
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            if (row.Ratio_Area > 0.05 and row.Ratio_NDVI > 1.5):
                row.Final = 1
                rows.updateRow(row)
            if (row.Ratio_Area > 0.05 and row.Ratio_NDVI < 0.5):
                row.Final = 1
                rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

In this code, how can I generalize the field name variable (row.NDVI090906). In above, NDVI090906 is a field name, where this field name follows the pattern of the name of the file. For example, if the file name is 'NVF_090906' the corresponding field name is NDVI090906. How can I make this field name as a variable so that when it loops through, it automatically performs computation of field names of other feature classes.

Comment: Is the end of the file name always 6 numbers? Can it include numbers? Give us some details about the file name. It may be a simple matter of parsing it apart into separate variables, but we need to know what may or may not change about the name first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a shot.  @Jason had the right idea with using the `Get` and `Set` values.

I took your code and did three things.

1. I pulled the feature class name, split off the prefix, and used the second part as part of the `NDVI` and `M` variables.
2. Replaced instances of hard-coding field names with variable references.  This makes it easier if you need to change a field name, and reduces repetition.
3. Combined loops that were performing separate functions.  Reduces complexity of code, and multiple cycling through of rows.

I added comments to the code as necessary.  I parsed the feature class name based on your filter for creating the list.  You use an underscore (_) to separate the prefix of the name from the portion you want to use as part of the field names.  I use that as the object to split the string.  The 2nd half of the split is concatenated with a new prefix to form the two new field name variables that are unique to each featureclass.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\RG\Kings County\Test.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("NVF_*")

try:
    for fc in fcs:
        fcnamelast = fc.split('_',1)[1]
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            if row.Field_ID == 1:
                rows.deleteRow(row)
        del rows, row
        # This code adds up several fields like Ratio_NDVI, Ratio_Acres etc.
        # Create variables containing field names first, allowing ease of reuse
        fieldndvi = "Ratio_NDVI"
        fieldndvichild = "NDVI" + fcnamelast
        fieldm9 = "M" + fcnamelast
        fieldratarea = "Ratio_Area"
        fieldfinal = "Final"
        fieldnewarea = "NewArea"
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, fieldndvi, "float")
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, fieldratarea, "float")
        arcpy.AddField_management (fc, fieldfinal, "integer")
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldnewarea, "DOUBLE")
        # This code calculates area in square meter using existing datum coordinates of the vector file
        #Convert square meter to acres
        geometryField = arcpy.Describe(fc).shapeFieldName
        cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in cursor:
            AreaSqMet = row.getValue(geometryField).area
            AreaAcres = AreaSqMet * 0.00024711
            row.SetValue(fieldnewarea, AreaAcres)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        del row, cursor

        # This code calculates ratio of NDVI of child_fields to the average NDVI of parent field
        # This code calculates the ratio of acres of child fields to their corresponding parent field
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            ndvichildval = row.getValue(fieldndvichild)
            m9childval = row.getValue(fieldm9)
            if ndvichildval == 0: 
                row.SetValue(fieldndvi, (m9childval/m9childval)) 
            else:
                row.SetValue(fieldndvi, (m9childval/ndvichildval))
            #Area ratio calculation
            areaacresval = row.getValue("Acres")
            areanewval = row.getValue(fieldnewarea)
            row.SetValue(fieldratarea,areanewval/areaacresval)
            print ("Completed calculating ratio of acres") 
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
        # This code finds that field that has either Ratio_NDVI higher than 1.5 to its parent #field or less than 0.5 to its parent field and Ratio_Acres higher than 0.05. Then #comments this field as "Change"
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
        for row in rows:
            ratareaval = row.getValue(fieldratarea)
            ratndvival = row.getValue(fieldndvi)

            if (ratareaval > 0.05 and ratndvival > 1.5):
                row.SetValue(fieldfinal, 1)
                rows.updateRow(row)
            if (ratareaval > 0.05 and ratndvival < 0.5):
                row.SetValue(fieldfinal, 1)
                rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows, row
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `row.getValue('FieldName')` instead of `row.FieldName`. Using getValue lets you pass in a variable name for a field name instead of hard-coding it.

```
    nvdi_field = 'NDVI090606'
    m9_field = 'M090606'
    ratio_field = 'Ratio_NDVI'
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
    for row in rows:
        if row.getValue(nvdi_field) == 0: 
            row.setValue(ratio_field, (row.getValue(m9_field)/row.getValue(m9_field)))
        else:
            row.setValue(ratio_field, (row.getValue(m9_field)/row.getValue(nvdi_field)))
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

You can also use `getattr(object, attribute)` and `setattr(object, attribute, value)` on any object in Python to get a similar behavior, allowing you to program in the field name to get/set.

Comment: But 'NDVI090606' is the field name associated to feature class 'NVF_090606'. When the 'for' loop loops for another feature class, e.g., NVF_052013, it flags error to ndvi_field. It is because, the field name for that feature class is NDVI052013. How to handle this?

Comment: Something like `nvdi_field = "NVDI" + fcnamelast`